# Why is my executeQuery hanging up?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm running what would seem as an otherwise simple piece of code. On its simplified form, it looks like this:

```
public class ReadDB throws SQLException {
    private Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement myStmt;

    public ReadDB(Connection connection) {
        conn = connection;
    }

    public List<GameEvent> getEvents(int gameId) {
        List<GameEvent> ret = new ArrayList<GameEvent>();
        myStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from logs where gameid=? order by id");
        myStmt.setInt(1, gameId);
        myStmt.setQueryTimeout(10); // Wasn't there before, doesn't really help
        ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery();
        while( rs.next() ) {
            // Do stuff, using "rs.getString()"
        }
        rs.close();
        myStmt.close()
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And this is what the database initialization looks like (the `connection` parameter):

```
String url=“jdbc:mysql://server.example.com/database_name”;
cProperties = new Properties();
cProperties.put(“user”, user);
cProperties.put(“password”, password);
// truncate field values that are too long
cProperties.put(“jdbcCompliantTruncation”, “false”); 
connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url,cProperties);
```

Now, my problem is: after calling the `getEvents` method several times (around 30), `executeQuery()` will just hang. No exception, no return value, nothing - it just stops there, probably in some kind of loop.

The database is read only, so there are no `INSERT` of any kind. Connecting to the (MySQL) database, `show processlist` lists the connection as `Sleep` while the connection time goes up. Of course, I can run the query just fine in a parallel window, but the Java program for some reason cannot. Also, it always hangs in a different `gameId`, so it's not related to that particular set.

Given that a very similar piece of code used to run just fine, I'm guessing that either I'm not opening/closing the connection the right way, or a network-related problem.

Ideas, anyone?

**Edit:** I updated the code according to address some of the comments, still with no positive results. Regarding debugging, the code seems to be stuck at the deepest level in

```
n = socketRead0(fd, b, off, length, timeout);
```

inside the `read()` function from `java.net.SocketInputStream`. The trace would be: an instance of `java.sql.PreparedStatement` (the one in the code) calls `executeQuery`, which calls `executeInternal`, which calls several `MysqlIO` functions, the deepest of which is `MysqlIO.readFully` (called by `MysqlIO.nextRowFast`). I can't peek inside this functions, but I can see them being called. I suspect, however, that this is too much detail, and that the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: What's sure is that you're already not closing the resultset the right way (it should be closed in a inally block), and that you're not closing the stztement at all. So I would also bet on a resource closing problem. But you're not showing us how you're opening and closing connections.

Comment: You should close your prepared statement always in the same method where you have created it! Perhaps you reach the limit of too many open statements (cursors).        *too slow ;)*

Comment: Did you use a debugger to see exactly where it hangs? is it waiting for a server's answer that doesn't come or doing some work in an infinite loop? Did  you look in the server to see the current executing queries? Why do you order by id when every row returned will have the same id ?

Comment: Are you creating/getting a new database connection every call? Or is it reusing one connection?

Comment: I'm reusing the same one.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced similar issue. The program actually stops and waits at the `executeQuery()` command.

But my issue gets resolved when I do the following :
  Commit my Oracle Database after I deleted the Table directly from Oracle 
  Client(Toad).